# React Flow - How to use data in Edge With Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a web interface, allowing to create graphs from boxes that I created.

I arrive at a stage where I want to create an Edge With Button, the button is for example a checkbox. And I would like to retrieve the information from this checkbox in my data.

To redo the example you can use the "Edge With Button" documentation from the React Flow library. (https://reactflow.dev/examples/edge-with-button)

My code is exactly the same, except that I added a checkbox in the button.

I also create a function in my hand that allows me to retrieve my items.

```
const sendGraph = () => {
    console.log(elements)
  }
```

```
[
        {
            "id": "dndnode_3",
            "type": "input",
            "position": {
                "x": 180,
                "y": 150
            },
            "data": {
                "label": "node3"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "dndnode_4",
            "type": "default",
            "position": {
                "x": 240,
                "y": 270
            },
            "data": {
                "label": "node4"
            }
        },
        {
            "source": "dndnode_3",
            "sourceHandle": null,
            "target": "dndnode_4",
            "targetHandle": null,
            "id": "reactflow__edge-dndnode_3null-dndnode_4null",
            "type": "buttonedge"
        }
    ]
```

I found a way to add a new field, like "data", but this is done when creating the Edge and so I don't have the checkbox value. I get an Edge like this:

```
{
            "data" : "Hello"
            "source": "dndnode_3",
            "sourceHandle": null,
            "target": "dndnode_4",
            "targetHandle": null,
            "id": "reactflow__edge-dndnode_3null-dndnode_4null",
            "type": "buttonedge"
        }
```

Environment :

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-flow-renderer": "^9.6.7",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3"
```

How can I retrieve the value of my checkbox and assign it for example to "data"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but I do not think it is a good practice at all.

Index.js

I added the "data" parameter in the "addEdge" method, with a "checkbox" variable initialized to "False".

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import ReactFlow, {
  removeElements,
  addEdge,
  MiniMap,
  Controls,
  Background,
} from 'react-flow-renderer';

import ButtonEdge from './ButtonEdge';

const onLoad = (reactFlowInstance) => reactFlowInstance.fitView();

const initialElements = [
  {
    id: 'ewb-1',
    type: 'input',
    data: { label: 'Input 1' },
    position: { x: 250, y: 0 },
  },
  { id: 'ewb-2', data: { label: 'Node 2' }, position: { x: 250, y: 300 } },

  {
    id: 'edge-1-2',
    source: 'ewb-1',
    target: 'ewb-2',
    type: 'buttonedge',
  },
];

const edgeTypes = {
  buttonedge: ButtonEdge,
};

const EdgeWithButtonFlow = () => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState(initialElements);
  const onElementsRemove = (elementsToRemove) =>
    setElements((els) => removeElements(elementsToRemove, els));
  const onConnect = (params) =>
    setElements((els) => addEdge({ ...params, type: 'buttonedge', data:{ "checkbox": False} }, els));

  return (
    <ReactFlow
      elements={elements}
      onElementsRemove={onElementsRemove}
      onConnect={onConnect}
      snapToGrid={true}
      edgeTypes={edgeTypes}
      onLoad={onLoad}
      key="edge-with-button"
    >
      <MiniMap />
      <Controls />
      <Background />
    </ReactFlow>
  );
};

export default EdgeWithButtonFlow;
```

ButtonEdge.js

I created a useState which allows me to manage the state of my checkbox, and during the update I modify the value of data.checkbox. If I do everything via data.checkbox, obviously the parent does not update the state of the checkbox, since he is not aware of it.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  getBezierPath,
  getEdgeCenter,
  getMarkerEnd,
} from 'react-flow-renderer';

import './index.css';

const foreignObjectSize = 40;

const onEdgeClick = (evt, id) => {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  alert(`remove ${id}`);
};

export default function CustomEdge({
  id,
  sourceX,
  sourceY,
  targetX,
  targetY,
  sourcePosition,
  targetPosition,
  style = {},
  data,
  arrowHeadType,
  markerEndId,
}) {
  const edgePath = getBezierPath({
    sourceX,
    sourceY,
    sourcePosition,
    targetX,
    targetY,
    targetPosition,
  });
  const markerEnd = getMarkerEnd(arrowHeadType, markerEndId);
  const [edgeCenterX, edgeCenterY] = getEdgeCenter({
    sourceX,
    sourceY,
    targetX,
    targetY,
  });

const [checkState, setCheckState] = useState("False")
const updateCheckBox= (evt, id) => {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        setCheckState(!checkState)
        data.checkbox= !data.checkbox
    };

  return (
    <>
      <path
        id={id}
        style={style}
        className="react-flow__edge-path"
        d={edgePath}
        markerEnd={markerEnd}
      />
      <foreignObject
        width={foreignObjectSize}
        height={foreignObjectSize}
        x={edgeCenterX - foreignObjectSize / 2}
        y={edgeCenterY - foreignObjectSize / 2}
        className="edgebutton-foreignobject"
        requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      >
        <body>
          <button
            className="edgebutton"
            onClick={(event) => onEdgeClick(event, id)}
          >
            <CheckBox  onClick={(event) => updateCheckBox(event, id)} value={checkState}/>
          </button>
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
    </>
  );
}
```

If there is another way, maybe more "better practice friendly", I am interested.